# Java error when I separate declaration and assginment of a variable: <identifier> expected

Tags: java

```
public class number{
    public int a;
    a = 300;

    public void print_num(int i){
        System.out.println(i);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        number n1 = new number();
        n1.print_num(n1.a);
    }
}


 --------------------------

 number.java:3: error: <identifier> expected
```

Hi. I'm a noob in Java.
It seems really simple but I don't know why. 
I'd like to separate declaration of variable & assignment of variable.

Could you let me know how?

Comment: You can do public int a = 300;

Comment: Read the [Naming Conventions](http://java.about.com/od/javasyntax/a/nameconventions.htm).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only declarations can exist in a class outside of a block of code such as a method or a constructor.  You can't have the assignment away from the declaration outside of a block of code.

If you'd like to assign a value apart from the declaration, then the assignment must be in a method, constructor, or an initializer block.

Comment: Thank you for replying! then if I write "public int a = 300;" why does it work?

Comment: There, a combination of declaration and initialization is allowed, and a declaration by itself is allowed, but not a statement by itself.

Answer (score 2):

`a = 300;` is executable statement which needs to be under executable block (method, constructor, internalizer block_

Comment: thank you for replying! then if I write "public int a = 300;" why does it work?

Comment: because it is allowed as part of declare time initialization